# Controlling order of blocks in Magento layout.xml - jQuery CDN appearing after added skinjs

Tags: layout, blocks, javascript

Having some trouble rendering jQuery in my Magento theme via local.xml in an appropriate position.

Currently, the section in question in my layout.xml looks like so:

```
<!-- load jQuery from CDN with local fallback, latest version 1.11.0 -->
<block type="core/text" name="google.cdn.jquery">
    <action method="setText">
        <text><![CDATA[<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script><script>window.jQuery||document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">\x3c/script>');</script><script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]></text>
    </action>
</block>

<!-- add global JS functions library -->
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>min/global-min.js</name></action>
```

However the global-min.js file here is rendered **before** jQuery, which (along with other added core/text type blocks) is sitting after the rest of my skin JS files.

Is there a way to move the CDN loaded jQuery file up in terms of output priority inside the head of my site?

Thanks very much for your help.

*Note: apologies if this is considered bad practice but I'm reposting a question I posted on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349584/controlling-order-of-blocks-in-magento-layout-xml-jquery-cdn-appearing-after-a) as I thought this might be a more appropriate forum.*

Answer (score 1):

Found a couple of solutions to my original problem:

1. Call the *google.cdn.jquery* block in via `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('google.cdn.jquery') ?>` *before* the `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>` block in my **head.phtml** template, and then use `<?php echo $this->unsetChild('favicon.extra') ?>` to reposition the block (to avoid duplication).
2. Utilise another block in the footer to call my global functions relying on jQuery as per the answer provided here: [Is there any way to add JS/CSS to footer page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15904/is-there-any-way-to-add-js-css-to-footer-page).

Number 2 is the solution I chose to go with as it indirectly but clearly solved the underlying issue I was facing.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout file to achieve this.

```
 <default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="google.cdn.jquery" template="custom/head/head.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

Now define the template

File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/custom/head/head.phtml`

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('min/global-min.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery||document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">\x3c/script>');</script><script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

This will definitely solve your problem and your layout file looks more clean :)

Comment: While this could work somewhat (note: I need global-min.js to be placed _after_ jQuery as it relies on it), it sort of means I lose control of the global-min.js file through layout.xml. It does give me a good idea for grouping all of my CDN loaded scripts into a template file though. Unfortunately not exactly the solution I'm looking for overall.

Comment: if you need `global-min.js` after jquery, you can alter template file accordingly and achive it. Defining template file provides you a reliable way to adjust your scripts. You can use this template file to load any script file in any order. I think this is the best way that you can rely on